# Recaptcha bypass on vue-recaptcha

Tags: vue.js, recaptcha, rpa

I am using online services to bypass recaptcha on my RPA tool, and they are working great for quite some time.

However I found a specific website, which is using vue-recaptcha lib. What happens here, is that this lib has all their code and listeners encapsulated into their Vue components, so I cannot just put the recaptcha code inside the textarea field and continue the flow.

Anyone has faced anything similar or has any insights I could use on this case?

Answer (score 1):

One occasion something similar happened to me, and it turned out that there was a JavaScript function to send the ReCaptchaV2 solution, in that case it was called

> captchaCallBack()

You had to put the solution in the textArea and call the function.

Comment: Not the case here. Using this component there is no explicit function to be called. They bind a listener directly to google url. I dont have name neither scope to call this function.